# Argo Workflow args using echo to redirect to file without printing

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows

I have the following Argo Workflow using a Secret from Kubernetes:

```
args:
      - |
        export TEST_FILENAME="./test.txt"
        echo "$TEST_DATA" > $TEST_FILENAME
        chmod 400 $TEST_FILENAME
      env:
      - name: TEST_DATA
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: test_data
            key: testing
```

I need to redirect `TEST_DATA` to a file when I run the Argo Workflow, but the data of `TEST_DATA` always shows in the argo-ui log. How can I redirect the data to the file without showing the data in the log?

Comment: Can you post more of the workflow? Specifically, I'd like to see the `command`.

Comment: can not post the command, is there a way to use the enviroment variable without printing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo` shouldn't be writing `$TEST_DATA` to logs the way your code is written. So I'm not sure what's going wrong.

However, I think there's an easier way to [write a secret to a file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#projection-of-secret-keys-to-specific-paths). Add a volume to your Workflow spec, and a volume mount to the `container` section of the step spec.

```yaml
  containers:
  - name: some-pod
    image: some-image
    volumeMounts:
    - name: test-mount
      mountPath: "/some/path/"
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    secret:
      secretName: test_data
      items:
      - key: testing
        path: test.txt
```

Comment: ok, thanks!

should still need to use the env, valueFrom and secretKeyRef?

env:
      - name: TEST_DATA
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: test_data
            key: testing

Comment: @ratzip you can if you want! You can load the secret both to a file and to an env var, using the code from your original post. I'm still not sure how the env var is ending up in the logs, but without more context, I don't think I'll be able to help.

Comment: @ratzip but if you just need the file, there's no need to include the code from your original post. Only use that if you specifically need the secret in an env var.

Comment: @ratzip you bet!